# Failed building wheel for GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient

Tags: linux, google-app-engine

I get this error when trying to install google cloud:

```
  Failed building wheel for GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient
  Running setup.py clean for GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient
Failed to build GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient
Installing collected packages: GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient
  Running setup.py install for GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jZCvYX/GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-LgTihN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= --home=/tmp/tmprq5a80:
    running install
    error: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base
```

this is installed on the /lib folder, I also made a requirements.txt 
as well as the appengine_config.py.

Also I am using python 2.7, on linux

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" <package_name>
```

However, better to [install the whole Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#linux) as it includes: command line tools (gcloud, gsutil, bq) in addition to client libraries.